How can I make this function take up less memory?
I've written a sketch that uses TimeLib to display elapsed time. I'm measuring how long it takes to drain a battery. The goal is to display the time as hh:mm:ss.
The code I use works well when I create a sketch that only contains this code.
But when I run it as part of the complete program, displaying the time fails: the getTime function seems to be returning an empty string.
Specifically:
String gTime = String(addZero(hour())) + ":";

this works, but when I add more,
String gTime = String(addZero(hour())) + ":" + String(addZero(minute()));

the returned string is incomplete: I get ":00" instead of 00:00"
I suspect a memory problem, so I'm looking for ways to make this sketch use less memory.
I've been reading that String variables take up a lot of space, and I should use char arrays instead. But every attempt I made to rewrite these functions has failed.
#include <TimeLib.h>

unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
const long interval = 1000; //in ms

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200); 
  Serial.println("Start program"); 
  setTime(00,00,00,01,01,2024);
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
    String Tm = getTime();
    Serial.print(Tm);Serial.println(";");   
  }
}

String getTime(void) {
  String gTime = String(addZero(hour())) + ":" + String(addZero(minute())) + ":" + String(addZero(second()));
  return gTime;
}

String addZero(int digits) {
  String Dig = "0";
  if(digits < 10) {
    Dig = "0" + String(digits);
  }
  else {
    Dig = String(digits);
  }
  return Dig;
}

Here's my attempt so far. This produces correct output for 10 to 59, but fails for 1 to 9. And the function still returns a String instead of a char array.
String addZero(int digits) {
  char Dig[3] = "00";

  if(digits < 10) {
    itoa(digits,Dig[1],10);
  }
  else {
    itoa(digits,Dig,10);
  }
  return Dig;
}

I'm stuck. How do I get this to work?

did you see the TimeSerialDateStrings example of the TimeLib?

Yes, I saw that example and adapted it to get the time into a variable instead of just printing it.

Use snprintf() here for formatted printing instead of the String class. Leading zeros can sometimes be interpreted as OCTAL.
#include <TimeLib.h>

unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
const long interval = 1000; //in ms
char buf[20] = {0} ;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200); 
  Serial.println("Start program"); 
  setTime(00,00,00,01,01,2024);  // don't use leading zeros here !!
}


void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
    snprintf( buf, sizeof(buf)-1,"%02d:%02d:%02d", hour(), minute(), second()) ;
    Serial.println(buf) ;

    // if you want to copy it into another char array
    char newBuf[15] ;
    strncpy( newBuf, buf, sizeof(newBuf)) ;
    Serial.println( newBuf ) ;

    // if you want it in a String:
    String str1 = String( buf ) ;
    Serial.println( str1 ) ;
  }
}


That would take care of printing, but can I store the formatted time in a variable? I want to record the time at which the battery was drained.

I've added a couple of examples of getting the formatted string into a variable. Maybe you also want the date in the buffer ?

That's very helpful, thanks. This works in the test program. The full program still won't display the time, so I'll have to find more ways to reduce the memory footprint.

OK. Best to post the entire program (maybe as a separate thread) to get ideas on how to reduce the runtime size. One thing is this: Serial.println("Start program"); . You can do this instead: Serial.println(F("Start program")) ;. The F() macro in this case keeps the string "Start program" from using RAM. The compiler gives statistics on memory usage which can help but it can't see everything (Automatic variables, heap usage etc.)

snprintf adds 1 kB flash use

If the compiler/linker does not complain, "memory" problems are usually dynamic RAM, which cannot be checked at compile time. String objects are the first idea to remove when dealing with RAM issues. (BTW: A complete RTC timestamp is just 6 bytes)

I've made a new question with the entire program: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/96625/how-can-i-make-this-program-take-up-less-memory

Couldn't you have amended this question? Two very similar questions are not in the spirit of how this site should be used. I'm going to close this question so that answers are not split between the two questions.

I followed the suggestion in 6v6gt's comment.

Mea Culpa. I did make the suggestion which I acknowledge was wrong in retrospect. I did, however, assume that the OP had  made a more comprehensive attempt to eliminate Strings, after the first answer, hence the suggestion to open a new thread including the full code which could flush out more general size reduction ideas.
