How can I make this program take up less memory?
I'm measuring how long it takes to drain a battery. An Arduino Nano controls an SSD1036 OLED display, a board with two relays, and an INA3221 voltage/current measurement board.
The battery is connected to the INA3221, then to a resistor. A relay in this circuit allows me to disconnect the battery.
I've tested each part of the setup separately, and it all works. When I combine the code into a single program, the getTime() function stops working. It is supposed to return the time as a formatted string (12:34:56), but it returns an empty string instead.
I've rewritten that function to use less memory, but that was insufficient: when I run the full program, with the time function modified as indicated in the linked question, the getTime() call still returns an empty string.
When I compile, I get this report:

Sketch uses 23088 bytes (75%) of program storage space. Maximum is 30720 bytes.
Global variables use 806 bytes (39%) of dynamic memory, leaving 1242 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.

Because smaller parts of this program do work, I suspect I'm running out of memory. How can I fit this program into the memory of the Nano?
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>
#include <TimeLib.h>
#include <INA3221.h>
#include <Bounce2.h>

//D4 is relay 1, D5 is relay 2
#define Rel1 4
#define Rel2 5

//buttons
const int inputPin1 = 2;//D2 -stop measurement
const int inputPin2 = 6;//D6 - start measurement
Bounce bouncer1 = Bounce(); 
Bounce bouncer2 = Bounce(); 
int buttonState = LOW;
int stopMeting = 0;
int stopMeting1 = 0;
int stopMeting2 = 0;
float stopVoltage = 1.30;
String stopTijd1;
String stopTijd2;


//SSD1036 OLED
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 128 // OLED display width, in pixels
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 64 // OLED display height, in pixels
#define OLED_RESET     -1 // Reset pin # (or -1 if sharing Arduino reset pin)
#define SCREEN_ADDRESS 0x3C ///< See datasheet for Address; 0x3D for 128x64, 0x3C for 128x32
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, &Wire, OLED_RESET);

//timer
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
const long interval = 1000; //in ms
char buffer[20] = {0};

//INA3221
#define SERIAL_SPEED 115200 
#define PRINT_DEC_POINTS 3 

INA3221 ina_0(INA3221_ADDR42_SDA);

float voltage1 = 0.0;
float current1 = 0.0;
float voltage2 = 0.0;
float current2 = 0.0;
float power1 = 0.0;
float power2 = 0.0;
float energy1 = 0.0;
float energy2 = 0.0;
float dEnergy1 = 0.0;
float dEnergy2 = 0.0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Start program");
  //buttons
  pinMode(inputPin1,INPUT_PULLUP);
  bouncer1.attach(inputPin1);
  pinMode(inputPin2,INPUT_PULLUP);
  bouncer2.attach(inputPin2);
  //relay
  pinMode(Rel1,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(Rel1,LOW);
  pinMode(Rel2,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(Rel2,LOW);

  //oled
  if(!display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, SCREEN_ADDRESS)) {
    Serial.println(F("SSD1306 allocation failed"));
    for(;;); // Don't proceed, loop forever
  }
  display.clearDisplay();
  // Draw a single pixel in white
  display.drawPixel(10, 10, SSD1306_WHITE);
  display.display();
  delay(2000);

  //time
  setTime(00,00,00,01,01,2024);

  //INA
  current_measure_init();
  delay(2000);

}

void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  bouncer1.update();
  int debouncedInput1 = bouncer1.read();
  bouncer2.update();
  int debouncedInput2 = bouncer2.read();
  
  if ( bouncer2.changed() ) {
    int debouncedInput2 = bouncer2.read();
    if ( debouncedInput2 == LOW ) {
      startMeting();
    }
  }


  if ( bouncer1.changed() and stopMeting == 0) {
    int debouncedInput1 = bouncer1.read();
    if ( debouncedInput1 == LOW ) {
      eindMeting();
      stopMeting = 1;
    }
  }

  String Tm = getTime();
  voltage1 = ina_0.getVoltage(INA3221_CH1);
  voltage2 = ina_0.getVoltage(INA3221_CH2);

  if (voltage1 < stopVoltage and stopMeting1 == 0) {
    stopMeting1 = 1;
    digitalWrite(Rel1,LOW);
    stopTijd1 = Tm;
  }
    if (voltage2 < stopVoltage and stopMeting2 == 0) {
    stopMeting2 = 1;
    digitalWrite(Rel1,LOW);
    stopTijd2 = Tm;
  }

  if (stopMeting1 == 1 and stopMeting2 == 1) {
    stopMeting = 1;
    eindMeting();
  }

  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
    if (stopMeting == 0) {
      updatedisplay(currentMillis);
      }
    }  
  
}
void startMeting(void) {
  digitalWrite(Rel1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Rel2,HIGH);
}

void eindMeting(void) {
  digitalWrite(Rel1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(Rel2,LOW);
  setupdisplay();
  display.println("Eind meting");
  String Tm = getTime();
  Serial.println("Eind meting ");
  Serial.print(Tm);Serial.print(";");
  Serial.print(current1);Serial.print(";");
  Serial.print(voltage1);Serial.print(";");
  Serial.print(current2);Serial.print(";");
  Serial.print(voltage2);Serial.print(";");
  Serial.print(dEnergy1);Serial.print(";");
  Serial.print(dEnergy2);Serial.println(";");
  display.print("time "); display.println(Tm);
  display.print("E1 ");display.println(dEnergy1);
  display.print("E2 ");display.println(dEnergy2);
  //display.println(stopTijd1);display.println(stopTijd2);
  display.display();
}

void setupdisplay(void) {
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setTextSize(1);      // Normal 1:1 pixel scale
  display.setTextColor(SSD1306_WHITE); // Draw white text
  display.setCursor(0, 0);     // Start at top-left corner
  display.cp437(true);         // Use full 256 char 'Code Page 437' font
}

void updatedisplay(unsigned long currentMillis) {
  //INA
  current1 = ina_0.getCurrent(INA3221_CH1) * 1000; 
  voltage1 = ina_0.getVoltage(INA3221_CH1);
  current2 = ina_0.getCurrent(INA3221_CH2) * 1000;
  voltage2 = ina_0.getVoltage(INA3221_CH2);
  power1= current1 * voltage1;
  power2= current2 * voltage2;
  if (stopMeting1 == 0) {
    energy1= energy1 + power1; //in mWs
  }
    if (stopMeting2 == 0) {
    energy2= energy2 + power2; //in mWs
  }
  dEnergy1 = (energy1/3600); //in mWh
  dEnergy2 = (energy2/3600); //in mWh
  String Tm = getTime();
  Serial.print(Tm);Serial.print(";");
  Serial.print(current1);Serial.print(";");
  Serial.print(voltage1);Serial.print(";");
  Serial.print(current2);Serial.print(";");
  Serial.print(voltage2);Serial.print(";");
  Serial.print(dEnergy1);Serial.print(";");
  Serial.print(dEnergy2);Serial.println(";");
  setupdisplay();
  display.print("time ");display.println(Tm);
  display.print(hour());display.print(minute());display.println(second());
  display.print("I1 ");display.println(current1);
  display.print("V1 ");display.println(voltage1);
  display.print("I2 ");display.println(current2);
  display.print("V2 ");display.println(voltage2);
  display.print("E1 ");display.println(dEnergy1);
  display.print("E2 ");display.println(dEnergy2);
  display.display();
}

String getTime(void) {
  snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1,"%02d:%02d:%02d", hour(), minute(), second());
  return buffer;
}

void current_measure_init() {
    ina_0.begin(&Wire);
    ina_0.reset();
    ina_0.setShuntRes(100, 100, 100);
}


This question is similar to: How can I make this function take up less memory?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

As indicated in the other question, modifying the getTIme call as the answer suggested did not make the program small enough to fit yet.

don't repeat code

If you suspect a memory problem, remove all instances of the String class from your program. Use char buffers and the corresponding C functions instead. If it then still doesn't work your problem is somewhere else

This doesn't look like a memory problem. There's plenty of dynamic memory left.  I'm suspect of the function that tries to return a char array as a String but I'm not sure if that's actually a problem or not.

Further to @Delta_G's comment, the buffer is already a global char array that can be accessed by all the functions, there is no need to return it as a String.

Your initial memory allocations are pretty light. Program memory use isn't going to increase during the run, and I don't see any dynamic allocations from RAM, besides the call-stack, of course, which is well-behaved -- until/unless there are enough nested function-calls to over-write some static allocations (globals, typically). Without that, you aren't likely running out of memory.
Places to start looking are: 1) In the standard Arduino library, printf() and friends don't implement printing of floats. I don't know well behaved they are if you try. 2) Perhaps you're over-writing a some variable - an address or pointer, especially?
You say you've tested the pieces but the full program fails. I'd try adding in one piece at a time and test that much, until something fails. Then do it again but adding pieces in a different order. Does it fail on the same added piece or a different one?
Another approach is to replace each function, one at a time - with a stub - a function that has the same name and parameters but which does nothing except to return a valid value (if any return value is required). Or returns 'false' or an invalid value, if you suspect that to be what triggers the failure. Replace one function at a time by a stub until the program "works" (minus what that function was supposed to do, obviously) with the stub but fails with the function's full code. Now you can start stubbing major sections of that function's code, until again, the program starts working. Narrow the stubbed out section again, etc, ..., until you find the offending statement(s).

String getTime(void) {
  snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1,"%02d:%02d:%02d", hour(), minute(), second());
  return buffer;
}

Since the result is already in buffer, why return it as a String? This could well cause heap fragmentation.
I strongly suggest you rewrite the entire code without using the String type.
